# How to protect expressions in the 'find' command from interpretation by the shell?

Tags: bash, find, quoting

I would like to run the command `find . '! -name *.*'` in the `bash` shell. It does not work as intended. (It should list all files in the current directory for which `-name *.*` is false, i.e. which do not have a dot in their names.) Instead, it prints a list of all files in the directory and, paradoxically, ends with the line `find: "! -name *.*": file or directory not found`. I suspect the problem is interpretation of the expression by the shell, although it is protected by the two apostrophe (U+0027) characters. Are there ways to protect the expression *reliably* whatever the expression is?

I use this version: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the OP quoting the expr `'! -name *.*'` it turns into the 2nd argument to `find`. So now what
`find` thinks is that you passed to it `2` directory names, viz., `.` and a crazy name `! -name *.*`, so it'll faithfully try to list out all files/subdirs recursively in these two. With `.` so far so good, but when the time comes to dive into that crazy dir. `! -name *.*` it can't, unless you have it. And even then, `find` won't be doing what you wanted.

For that you have to quote at the proper places:

```
find . ! -name '*.*'
```

or

```
eval find . '! -name "*.*"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the single quotes around the expression only.

```
find . ! -name '*.*'
```